# GWTBootStrap3 DateTimePicker ShowRangeHandler missing

Tags: java, gwt, bootstrap-datepicker, gwtbootstrap3

It seems there isn't a method like showRangeHandler in the GWTBootstrap3 porting of the GWT DatePicker. There is a method ShowHandler but I can't figure out how to use it. I need to prevent the user's selection of a date before tomorrow. I've read some other discussions about that but all talk about this showRangeHandler which is missing in DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setStartDate](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/extras-apidocs/org/gwtbootstrap3/extras/datetimepicker/client/ui/base/constants/HasStartDate.html#setStartDate-java.util.Date-) to set earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be disabled.

Comment: setStartDate() simply set the start date but doesn't disable the selection of previous dates. Already done.